# If you gently squeeze me with your hands, I'll get hard like a potato

Tags: riddle

If you gently squeeze me with your hands, I'll get hard like a potato.
Can you guess what I am?

(This is my translation of a famous riddle.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are, perhaps,

> **snow**, or a **snowball**.
>
>  Loose packing snow is not particularly solid, but squeezed gently it compresses nicely into a firm snowball.

Comment: Wow, this is the correct answer. Adults are notoriously bad at cracking this puzzle :)

Comment: Discarding any notoriously bad possible answers as being, well, notorious, helps narrow in on better and more likely answers. :)

Comment: I don't want to eat the OP's potatoes if they are that hard.

Comment: And like a potato if you put them in an oven they get 'softer'